# Having trouble unwrapping my variables

Tags: ios, swift

**EDIT 1: All spots where I define something related to the "author" variable (at bottom)**

Can someone tell me why my labels still say "Optional()". My variables should be getting unwrapped through this code, should they not ? I am getting JSON data, parsing it into local objects and then using those objects in a table view (and a subsequent detail view) with labels.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let row = indexPath.row

guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(EditorialTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? EditorialsTableViewCell else {
    print ("error: editorialsTableView cell is not of class EditorialsTableViewCell, we will use RandomTableViewCell instead")
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(EditorialTableCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RandomTableViewCell
}

if let editorialObject = editorialObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? EditorialElement {
    // we just unwrapped editorialObject

    let title = editorialObject.title ?? "" // if editorialObject.title == nil, then we return an empty string.

    let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(editorialObject.timeStamp))
    let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject)

    let author = editorialObject.author ?? ""

    let issueNumber = editorialObject.issueNumber ?? ""
    let volumeNumber = editorialObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

    let articleContent = editorialObject.articleContent ?? ""

    let nodeID = editorialObject.nodeID ?? 0


    cell.editorialHeadlineLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    cell.editorialHeadlineLabel.text = title

    cell.editorialAuthorLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
    cell.editorialAuthorLabel.text = String(author)

    cell.editorialPublishDateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
    cell.editorialPublishDateLabel.text = timeStampDateString

} else {

}

return cell
}
```

Class code:

```
class EditorialElement: NSObject {

var title: String           // title
var nodeID: Int             // nid
var timeStamp: Int       // revision_timestamp
var imageURL: String       // image_url
var author: String       // author

var issueNumber: String     // issue_int
var volumeNumber: String    // volume_int

var articleContent: String // html_content

init(title: String, nodeID: Int, timeStamp: Int, imageURL: String, author: String, issueNumber: String, volumeNumber: String, articleContent: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.nodeID = nodeID
    self.timeStamp = timeStamp
    self.imageURL = imageURL
    self.author = author
    self.issueNumber = issueNumber
    self.volumeNumber = volumeNumber
    self.articleContent = articleContent
}

override func isEqual(object: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    return (object as! EditorialElement).nodeID == self.nodeID
}

override var hash: Int {
    return (self as EditorialElement).nodeID
}

}
```

**EDIT 1: Here is everything related to author (after edits)**

In my IssueElement class:

```
    var author: String          // author
```

In my populateCurrentIssue function:

```
issueElement.author = String(node.1["author"])
```

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath (within the

```
if let currentIssueObject = currentIssueObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? IssueElement
```

loop.

```
let author = currentIssueObject.author
```

And finally:

```
cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
cell.currentIssueArticlesAuthorLabel.text = author
```

Comment: Actually all nil coalescing operators (??) are useless because according the declarations all variables are non-optionals witch never can be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, `editorialHeadlineLabel` should not show "Optional()" in any case.

`editorialAuthorLabel` can be optional because `String()` can be optional if the constructor fails to initialize a string.

`editorialPublishDateLabel` can be optional because `stringFromDate()` will return nil if you pass an invalid date.

Comment: You are indeed right. The headline never shows up as an optional. How can I make that be the case for the author as well ? The date almost always shows up unwrapped.

Comment: You can add default values with `??` like you have done before (eg. `let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject) ?? "Date unknown"` )

Comment: Yeah but what should I do to my "author" variable ? It already has the "?? "" " part and it is still being displayed as an optional. Same thing with articleContent. Any ideas ?

Comment: For `author` there is no need to convert it to `String()`, you should be able to do `cell.editorialAuthorLabel.text = author`. You should remove all the `??` for any non-optional variables too. Make sure your code is correct, clean your build (Cmd+K) and try again.

Comment: Check out my update code. I made an edit and it still doesn't work. Been trying to solve this stupid optional problem for the past three weeks. It's ridiculous...